# Is it impossible to make an Android game stutter-free? I am going crazy here

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an Android game for the past 6 months or so, and have posted on here several times about various lag issues that I cannot get rid of.

I ended up grabbing the LunarLander example and stripping it down to its very core components to see if I could make anything at all that doesn't lag. All it really does is change the amount the canvas is translated each frame, and then draw a background onto the canvas. EVEN THIS, about as simple as you can get for a surfaceView application - stutters...

My game is a scrolling game where you continuously move up the screen (think of a flying game), but the way I am currently doing the background results in constant stuttering every second or so for about 50-100ms. This isn't game breaking, but it is very distracting and makes the game seem as if it was programmed by a complete moron (though I am starting to suspect this might be the case).

No, it is not the garbage collector, there are no new objects being created at all during the game's run loop, and the GC barely ever runs while my game is running.

I am practically tearing my hair out with frustration. I have spent over 40 hours just trying to get rid of the lag on this simple application example over the past week alone and it is driving me crazy. How can an application as simple as the one I have linked possibly have lag issues? You wouldn't think a scrolling background could get much simpler than that...

NOTE: This demonstration constantly gets about 60fps on my phone (A Motorola Milestone). Uncomment the FPS code in the example to see the FPS.

TL;DR: Extraordinarily simple program that is just a scrolling background shows stuttering. Please have a look...

Link to download simple stuttering example based off the LunarLander example:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4972001/LunarLander.rar

Comment: Does the JetBoy demo have stuttering when it runs on your phone? http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/JetBoy/index.html

Comment: What did Traceview tell you? Also, in the future, please skip the flame-bait headlines.

Comment: Sorry about the flame-bait, I was very frustrated when I wrote that out (as I am sure you can tell). Traveview shows nothing out of the ordinary. There are equal gaps between all draw/updatePhysics calls. It seems to be something that is visible but not measureable, which is confusing. Also, yes, JetBoy has stuttering issues as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have downloaded the RAR file with your scrolling background (looks like a grassy field), and installed it on my Motorolla Droid.

I can perceive no stuttering as it scrolls, I've watched it for well over a minute.

Based on your description I'd wager the Milestone hardware/platform has some weird video drawing/timing issue.

Perhaps the explanation is something along the lines of this: The Milestone's diplay refreshes at 60 Hz (just picking a number here, I don't know what it really is), and your frame rate is just slightly off that - say 63 or 57 Hz ... is it not conceivable that approx once a second the timing of your draw, and the timing of the hardware display update mismatch just enough that the background doesn't get a re-draw that one time, and has to wait until your next frame? And that occasionally the timing lines up just enough that you might miss the timing of two or three draws in a row (depending upon how far off your frame-cycle is from the actual screen refresh cycle).

EDIT:  Actually, I watched it for another minute I did did see one very short (just perceivable) stutter.

Comment: This was one of my theories actually (the refresh rate being a bit off the FPS), but I have no idea how to fix that... Do you think there would be any easy way to fix that kind of an issue?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  In my experience with game coding on other platforms in days of yor (e.g. playstation 1, sega saturn, etc.) the frame-rate was synced to the display rate by actually getting an hardware interrupt hook with the display driver.  Have no idea how you could do that with the Android platform.

Comment: Hmm, well I have seen the stuttering on both mine and a friend's phone (Nokia N900 running Android 2.2). I am wondering if it just effects a small group of phones.

Comment: Even if the VSync and fps are not synced. This can only cause the image to not get updated for 1/60th of a second, I dont think that is so noticable as the problem described here. Also VSync on Flat-Panels works quite a bit different than as on the big old CRTs.

Comment: You could try to prove the theory by purposely setting a framerate in the main loop (e.g. making sure the loop takes some specific amount of time), and then theoretically (depending upon the timing) you would see either no stutters or lots of stutters - depending upon what the display's refresh rate is and the fps that you chose to impose.  You might try a few different fps settings just to be sure.   ... Just a quick thought.  Good luck.

Comment: @Roy T.  - note the theory that when the timing gets off, it will be off for more than one cycles in a row?  Though I'll admit it is a hasty and loose theory, but the only one I've got, and thought I'd share it.  Also, I fully understand that an LCD works differently from a CRT, but I'm not talking about the actual LCD, I'm talking about the graphics controller (the thing that every so often tells the lcd what to display).

Comment: Btw guys, the Droid and the Milestone are the same Hardware, just the US vs. EU version

Comment: Yeah, I know that... but it doesn't stutter on my Droid, so it seems like there must be SOME difference.  Maybe it's the electrons in EU.

Comment: I ran FrinkTheBrave's code below to limit fps, it shows it is likely to be something to do with the sync as a 20ms frame-time limit stutters like crazy, while a 33ms (so lower fps) frame-time limit does not stutter anywhere near as much (still stutters though).

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this same lag issue in my game (and I did something similar you did to LunarLander loop and reached a similar conclusion). If you open logcat, you see can that the lags happens together with GC_FOR_MALLOC (50 ... 100 ms, our lags time). I suspected the source of the problem was the garbage collector. Then I found this post:

http://fanitis.com/2011/02/09/android-game-performance-garbage-collection/

I'll try to reduce the use of garbage collector and see if I achieve a lagless condition hehehe =]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered jhouse's suggestion of a minimum frame time?

I am using that idea on my current project. I expect phone hardware to have made considerable improvements in the next year or two so this will stop your game becoming unplayable in future.

My code is like this:

```
    long frameTime;  // calculate time to process this frame

    while (mSurfaceAvailable) {
        // ensure minimum frame time can be calculated
        frameTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        // code to move everything and display a single frame goes here

        // ensure minimum frame time
        frameTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - frameTime;
        if (frameTime < 0) frameTime = MIN_FRAME_TIME;     // cope with wrap-around of uptimeMillis
        if (frameTime < MIN_FRAME_TIME) {
            /*DEBUG*/Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "run: Sleeping for "+(MIN_FRAME_TIME - frameTime)+"ms");
            try {
                sleep(MIN_FRAME_TIME - frameTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                /*DEBUG*/Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "run: Thread sleep was interrupted (not a problem)");
            }
        } else {
            if (frameTime != MIN_FRAME_TIME) {
                /*DEBUG*/Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "run: System is too slow, by "+(frameTime - MIN_FRAME_TIME)+"ms per frame");
            }
        }
```

I got the sleep exception handling from a forum (probably this one!) but have never seen the exception thrown

Comment: Now this is interesting. I implemented your above code, if I set my game to a 20ms MIN_FRAME_TIME it has considerably more lag than if I set it to a 33ms MIN_FRAME_TIME. You'd expect the opposite... EDIT: It is smoother again with a 16ms MIN_FRAME_TIME. EDIT2: It still stutters, however. Though possibly less than before.

Comment: What do you mean by lag? The larger the MIN_FRAME_TIME the slower the game will be. I don't know how the logging would affect things so try replacing all /*DEBUG*/ with //DEBUG*/